# How to replace part of a site, without reloading the entire site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, visual-studio-2017

Here is the relevant code:

```
<body>
    <h1>Music Nation</h1>
    <div id="navBar">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="Welcome.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="Trance.html" id="tranceGen">Trance</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="MS.html"  id="artistMS">Markus Schulz</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
           </li>
       </ul>
     </div>
     <div id="pjax-container">
             some text that should be replaced...
     </div>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#tranceGen").click(function () {

                e.preventDefault();
                $("#pjax-container").load("Trance.html #pjax-container");

            });
        });
</script>
</body>
```

As far as I've read on the internet, by using this it should replace just a certain part of the page without reloading the whole page, but for some reason it doesn't work. It still loads the entire page.

I've read how to use it from: http://api.jquery.com/load/
I've also read a few tutorials and I've read other questions here about the same subject, but nothing I try seems to work.

I've also tried something else I've read in another tutorial, to remove the default action(load the page I clicked I presumed), by adding "e.preventDefault();", but that had no effect either.

What am I doing wrong?
I want to load the content of the "#pjax-container" in the "Trance.html" page in the current page's "#pjax-container" without reloading the entire page.
I'm using Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 7 if that's somehow relevant.

Also, in the "head" section I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.pjax.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: remove # from id attribute  <div id="#pjax-container"> and missing close quotes

Comment: you also need to pass `e` into the function: `$("#tranceGen").click(function (e) {`

Comment: The " <div id="pjax-container"> " is corect in the actual document, I wrote here wrong. I've added "e" in the function, but it still had no effect. ;(

Comment: Cross that, it worked, had to delete cache first. Thank you everybody for the input. <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <div id="#pjax-container">
             some text that should be replaced...
     </div>
```

replace id with pjax-container

```
  <div id="pjax-container">
             some text that should be replaced...
     </div>
```

Comment: Oh, excuse me, in the actual document it's "<div id="pjax-container>". I made a mistake, when I wrote about the problem here. Will edit ASAP.

Comment: e.preventDefault(); e is not defined. Use $("#tranceGen").click(function (e) { ...}). check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zggju6ee/

Comment: That was the problem, that "e" wasn't defined. Thank you so much! <3